# Apache Solr multiple phrase queries with OR

Tags: lucene, solr

I am using Apache Solr 1.4 with dismax, and I am trying to execute a search for the following two phrases:

"call number"
"dewey decimal"

I want to match documents that contain either of those phrases.  I get matches if I search for those phrases separately, but not together.

I tried queries like:

```
title:("call number" OR "dewey decimal")

title:["call number" TO "dewey decimal"]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you also test the following query ?

```
(title:"call number" OR title:"dewey decimal")
```

Comment: How would this work for keyword searches?  If the keywords come in from the user like this:

    q="call number" or "dewey decimal"

I've tried adding phrase fields and playing with the phrase slop, but can't seem to get this to work with keywords.